# What is the difference between success rate and reward when dealing with binary and sparse rewards?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, papers, reward-functions, hindsight-experience-replay

In OpenAI Gym "reward" is defined as:

> `reward` (float): amount of reward achieved by the previous action. The
> scale varies between environments, but the goal is always to increase
> your total reward.

I am training Hindsight Experience Replay on Fetch robotics environments, where rewards are sparse and binary indicating whether or not the task is completed. The [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01495.pdf) implementing HER uses **success rate** as a metric in its plots, like so:

[image]

On page 5 of the original paper, it is stated that the reward is binary and sparse.

When I print the rewards obtained during a simulation of `FetchReach-v1` trained with HER, I get the following values. The first column shows the reward and the second column shows the episode length.

[image]

As can be seen, at every time step, I am getting a reward, sometimes I get a $-1$ reward at every time step throughout the episode for a total of $-50$. The maximum reward I can achieve throughout the episode is $0$.

Therefore my question is: What is the reward obtained at each time-step? What does it represent and how is this different from the success rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 6 of the paper describes the exact reward functions, and why they were used:

> Goals: Goals describe the desired position of the object (a box or a
>   puck depending on the task) with some fixed tolerance of $\epsilon$ i.e. $G = \mathcal{R}^3$
>    and $f_g(s) = [|g − s_{object}| ≤ \epsilon]$, where $s_{object}$ is the position of
>   the object in the state s. The mapping from states to goals used in
>   HER is simply $m(s) = s_{object}$.
>
> Rewards: Unless stated otherwise we use binary and sparse rewards $r(s, a, g) = −[f_g(s 0 ) = 0]$ where $s'$ is
>   the state after the execution of the action a in the state s. We
>   compare sparse and shaped reward functions in Sec. 4.4.

So, at least in the base version (which I believe is your `fetchreach-v1`), the agent receives a reward of -1 for every timestep spent more than $\epsilon$ from the goal state, and a reward of 0 for every timestep spent within $\epsilon$ of the goal state. Thus, a score of -5.0 would seem to correspond to the agent moving directly to the goal and staying there, while a score of -50.0 would correspond to the agent failing to reach the goal state entirely.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. However, how does this qualify as a sparse reward if it is given at every time-step? Shouldn't the sparse (and binary) reward be given at the end of the episode indicating whether or not the task is completed?

Comment: @Rrz0 The authors have chosen to present this in a slightly confusing way, but maybe it's easier to think about this as an affine transformation of a sparse reward function? Imagine we chose to add 1 to every reward (so 0 reward for non-goal steps, and 1 for being in a goal). The optimal policy would be unchanged, so the agent will learn the same behaviors. However, the output would be a little harder to understand, because it isn't clear that a score of 50 is "good" (50 is a magic number). Personally, I might have just awarded 1/(max_steps) for each step in the right spot.